# Sidekiq - Reschedule failed job

Tags: redis, sidekiq

I have a background job using Sidekiq connecting to another service of mine like this:

```
  def perform(id)
      user = ABCClient.instance.user(id)
      ...
  end
```

Sometimes this ABCClient is down and I would like to reschedule the "perform" job in this case.
Like this:

```
  def perform(id)
      begin
          user = ABCClient.instance.user(id)
      rescue => e
          # Reschedule job
      end
      ...
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

`rescue => e
  self.class.perform_in(5.minutes, id)
end`

Comment: I have the following error "undefined method `minutes' for 5:Fixnum" - are you sure it can be done this way?

Comment: That's a Railsism. Requires activesupport.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, using Rails >= 6.0.1 you can simply set `sidekiq_options retry: 5` https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#customizing-error-handling